# El intent no me quiere funcionar para abrir otra activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

Buenas tardes amigos tengo un problema con los intents no se que me pasa quiero abrir otra activity desde una clase obviamente pasando el contexto de la activity desde donde quiero pasarla.

```
public class Informe implements Response.ErrorListener, Response.Listener<JSONObject> {


//Propiedades que ayudan a conectarnos con el webservices

 RequestQueue request;
 JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;

 //El contexto donde se maneja este informe de la aplicacion

Context InformarTrabajoContext;

//Propiedades propias del Informe
private String Conclusion;
private String DescripcionDelTrabajo;
private String Estad;
private int id_informe ;
private String Necesidades;

private int registro_empleado;

public Informe(String conclusion, String descripcionDelTrabajo, String estad, int id_informe, String necesidades, int registro_empleado) {
    Conclusion = conclusion;
    DescripcionDelTrabajo = descripcionDelTrabajo;
    Estad = estad;
    this.id_informe = id_informe;
    Necesidades = necesidades;
    this.registro_empleado = registro_empleado;
}


public Informe() {
}



public int getRegistro_empleado() {
    return registro_empleado;
}

public void setRegistro_empleado(int registro_empleado) {
    this.registro_empleado = registro_empleado;
}

public String getConclusion() {
    return Conclusion;
}

public void setConclusion(String conclusion) {
    Conclusion = conclusion;
}

public String getDescripcionDelTrabajo() {
    return DescripcionDelTrabajo;
}

public void setDescripcionDelTrabajo(String descripcionDelTrabajo) {
    DescripcionDelTrabajo = descripcionDelTrabajo;
}

public String getEstad() {
    return Estad;
}

public void setEstad(String estad) {
    Estad = estad;
}

public int getId_informe() {
    return id_informe;
}

public void setId_informe(int id_informe) {
    this.id_informe = id_informe;
}

public String getNecesidades() {
    return Necesidades;
}

public void setNecesidades(String necesidades) {
    Necesidades = necesidades;
}

 public void RegistrarInforme(Context contexto){

     this.InformarTrabajoContext = contexto;
     this.request = Volley.newRequestQueue(this.InformarTrabajoContext);
     llamarAlWebSerices();

 }

private void llamarAlWebSerices() {

    String url = "http://192.168.7.119/WebServicesGestionAsistencia/AgregarInforme.php?conclusion="+this.Conclusion+"&descripcion="+this.DescripcionDelTrabajo+"&necesidades="+this.Necesidades+"&registro_empleado="+this.registro_empleado+"&Estado="+this.Estad;
    url = url.replace(" ","%20");
    this.jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
    this.request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    //Toast.makeText(this.InformarTrabajoContext,"Agregado exitosamente"+error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent VolverVentanaAnterior = new Intent(this.InformarTrabajoContext, InformacionDelEmpleado.class);
    this.InformarTrabajoContext.startActivity(VolverVentanaAnterior);
}

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
     //Toast.makeText(this.InformarTrabajoContext,"Informe agregado correctamente",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent VolverVentanaAnterior = new Intent(this.InformarTrabajoContext, MainActivity.class);
    this.InformarTrabajoContext.startActivity(VolverVentanaAnterior);
}
```

}

tengo el contexto q recibo como parametro cuando se llama Registrar informe
y bueno sobre ese contexto trabajo y fijense en el metodo onResponse y en onErrorResponse quiero abrir otra activity pero me da error no se q pasa porq sera muchas gracias.

aqui abajo les paso el codigo que es desde donde llamo al metodo RegistrarInforme :

```
public class InformarTrabajo extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {


// Objetos del form

private EditText etDescripcion,etConclusion,etNecesidades;
private Button btnEnviarInforme;
private Spinner spinnerEstado;

//Objeto Informe

private Informe informeDeEmpleado;

//Registro del empleado

int registro_empleado;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_informar_trabajo);
    recuPerarRegistro();
    InicializarObjetosForm();
    setButtonEvents();

}

private void setButtonEvents() {

     this.btnEnviarInforme.setOnClickListener(this);

}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    llenarObjetoInforme();
    this.informeDeEmpleado.RegistrarInforme(InformarTrabajo.this);

}



private void llenarObjetoInforme() {

      this.informeDeEmpleado = new Informe();
      this.informeDeEmpleado.setConclusion(this.etConclusion.getText().toString());
      this.informeDeEmpleado.setDescripcionDelTrabajo(this.etDescripcion.getText().toString());
      this.informeDeEmpleado.setEstad(this.spinnerEstado.getSelectedItem().toString());
      this.informeDeEmpleado.setNecesidades(this.etNecesidades.getText().toString());
      this.informeDeEmpleado.setRegistro_empleado(this.registro_empleado);

}

private void InicializarObjetosForm() {
    this.etDescripcion = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etDescripcionTrabajoInforme);
    this.etConclusion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etConclusionInformeEmpleado);
    this.etNecesidades = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNecesidadesInformeEmpleado);
    this.spinnerEstado = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerEstadoInforme);
    this.btnEnviarInforme = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BtnEnviarInformeEmpleado);
}

private void recuPerarRegistro() {

     this.registro_empleado = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("registroEmleado");
    Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(this.registro_empleado),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

intenta en el onResponse poner este codigo que lo que hace es abrir la actividad que quieras.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), miActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Comment: explica tu respuesta, este código como ayuda al OP?

Comment: Hola, `startActivityForResult(intent, 0)` requiere mas argumentos